# How to test for types on react components and props

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I just wanted to test types on out-of-the-box react testing tools, it looks pretty straight forward what I wanted to do, but it just doesn't like it. Plus, would this be possible for other types?

```
test('Expect label to be of type string', () => {
  const testString = 'Test value'
  const { getByDisplayValue } = render(<Label text={testString}/>);
  expect(getByDisplayValue).toBe(string);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the type of something in JavaScript you can use the `typeof` operator and could write an expectation for that like this:

```
const aValue = 'Some string'
expect(typeof aValue).toEqual('string')
```

I'm not sure where `getByDisplayValue` comes from, but I also wouldn't expect it to be a String? it looks like an API from [testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries)?

Comment: Looks good but this does not test a specific prop of a component, `getByDisplayValue` i assumed this is the value of my `<Label/>` component

Comment: I was just showing you a code example of testing the type of something in general. I think one problem you'll run into without any other libraries is you can't easily get the props from a component. I would suggest Enzyme for testing that kind of thing